# Laravel not migrating after renaming files inside migration folder

Tags: laravel, database-migration

In laravel when creating migration using cmd files inside migrations folder are named like `2014_10_2_0001_create_users_table.php` on my migrations folder i renamed and changed it to example `ausertable.php` after changing  name when i try to run `php artisan migrate:fresh`  i got message

```
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Nothing to migrate.
```

i tried composer autoload but nothing works thanks.

Comment: I think all migration file name must be `%year%_%month%_%day%_%hour%%minutes%_name_of_class`.

Comment: @Bazaim thanks it worked i changed it for foriegnkey renaming constraint

Comment: I added a real answer, so you can mark it as "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, all migration file name must have the following structure :

`%year%_%month%_%day%_%hour%%minutes%_name_of_class`

And the class name must be : `NameOfClass`.